# Why is my variable uninitialized in a separate if test?

Tags: php, if-statement, initialization, strtotime

For the first run, I need to use dates that are six months prior to the last MySQL date `$row_recent[0]`. For all of the runs after 1, I am using a previous variable to store the previous date and then decrease the date by 6 months. I have confirmed that the first if test produces the expected result. (MySQL date - 6 Months). However, the second if test outputs `$startdate6m` as the PHP default due to `$previous_6m` being uninitialized. Any idea why it won't recognize `$previous_6m = $initial6m`?

```
<?php
$run_number = 0;
while ($run_number < 15) {
    $run_number++;
    if($run_number == 1){
        if ($month <= 06){
            $year6m = date("Y", strtotime($row_recent[0]))-1;                               
            $month6m = str_pad((12-(6-date("m", strtotime($row_recent[0])))), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $startdate6m = "'".$year6m."-".$month6m."-01'";
            $end_date = $startdate6m;
            $initial6m = $startdate6m;
        } else{
            $year6m = date("Y", strtotime($row_recent[0]));
            $month6m = str_pad(date("m", strtotime($row_recent[0]))-6, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);   
            $startdate6m = "'".$year6m."-".$month6m."-01'";
            $end_date = $startdate6m;
            $initial6m = $startdate6m;
        }
    }
    $previous_6m = $initial6m;
    if($run_number > 1){
        #  6 Month
        #  Decrement date by 6 months
        $month6m = date("m", strtotime($previous_6m));
        if ($month6m <= 06){
            $year6m = date("Y", strtotime($previous_6m))-1; 
            $month6m = str_pad((12-(6-date("m", strtotime($previous_6m)))), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $startdate6m = "'".$year6m."-".$month6m."-01'";
            $end_date = $startdate6m;
        } else{
            $year6m = date("Y", strtotime($previous_6m));
            $month6m = str_pad(date("m", strtotime($previous_6m))-6, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); 
            $startdate6m = "'".$year6m."-".$month6m."-01'";
            $end_date = $startdate6m;
        }
    }
    $previous_6m = $startdate6m;
}
?>
```

Comment: what does `$run_number` start out as? If you do `$run_number = 1` outside of this code, then your $run_number could NEVER be 1 inside, and your `if($run_number == 1)` test will always fail.

Comment: `$run_number` is initialized as zero. Corrected above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just overkill. All this code, in while loop, can be replaced with few lines, like:

```php
$previous_6m = new DateTime($row_recent[0]);
$previous_6m->modify('first day of this month');

$run_number = 0;
while ($run_number < 15) {
    $run_number++;
    $previous_6m->modify('-6 month');

    # do something with your new date
    echo '$previous_6m = ', $previous_6m->format('Y-m-d'), "\n";
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/64502)**.

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, you are setting $prvious_6m to $initial6m. On the first iteration, $intial6m is defined, but the second if statement will fail (as $run_number IS 1, not greater than, at that point). On iteration #2, the $intial6m is never set, as you don't get inside the first if statement because now $run_number > 1. The second iteration, however, does get inside the second if statement. So, you either need to change the second if statement to be inclusive of 1 for this to work, or put `$previous_6m = $initial6m` inside of the first if statement.

Cheers

Comment: Okay. In the first if statement, I need the `$startdate6m` for calculations for the first run `$run_number = 0`. For every run after the first one `$run_number > 1`, I need to decrease the dates by 6 months for each run starting with the `initial6m` date when `$run_number = 2`. By making the change you suggested, it still returns the default php date for `$previous6m`. Any ideas?

Comment: Move $run_number++ to the end of the loop, change the first if statement to read `if (!$run_number)`, and the second to read `if ($run_number)`.